# Multipage UICollectionView with View

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to create a collection view layout similar to the one used by Twitter and Product Hunt. I want to have a horizontal collection view to tab between data while also maintaining vertical scrolling in the tab I am in. I do not want to just change the datasource that is loaded into the UICollectionView. I have tried several different layouts but none of them have been successful.

Right now, I have a UIViewController with a UICollectionView & UIImageView object inside of it. The UIImageView's size is (3/8) of the UIViewController's frame and begins at (0,0). The UICollectionView's frame is equal to the UIViewController's frame but the cv is offset to be below UIImageView & its size is equal to the size of the UIViewController's view. The (1) cell inside the UICollectionView has a UICollectionView inside of it -- this can be configured with the data you want (multiple cells). This layout works fine for a single datasource.

However, when you want to have multiple datasources accessed by scrolling horizontally the layout breaks down. You have to change the flow layout of the outermost UICollectionView to horizontal. When you do this, you get a layout error because the size of the collection view is larger than than the view and you cannot scroll vertically.

If you reference the image I provided, I think you can infer what the desired layout should behave like. You should be able to access the other datasource by horizontal scrolling but also be able to scroll the current collection view full screen and not have it fixed to the bottom of the UIImageView. I tried adding logic to the scrollview delegate methods but that didn't work either. Thanks[image: ![Product Hunt UI]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz60u.png)

[image: Product Hunt UI]